# Alternative to the Observable Pattern?

Tags: java, android, design-patterns

I need to perform some tasks on `object1` when some state change happens on `object2`.
I was trying to use observable pattern in android, I mean to use Observer and Observable classes, so `object1` implements Observer and `object2` extends Observable. Unfortunately, `object2` already extends from another class, so I can't define it as an extension of Observable.

Is there another alternative to use this pattern? Maybe other classes that allow me to perform this behavior?

Thanks.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Simply add to `object2` a field of type `Observable` to which observers are added and on which `notifyObservers()` is called when something changes.

This is what's meant by "favor composition over inheritance".

Comment: thanks! that's  enough for me. kostja's solution also sounds good but it requires additional effort.

Comment: This is a "dangerous" solution. Though it will work for me too. But additionally you should have mentioned, to FINALIZE your class or at least declare all relevant properties as private. This is the only way to keep your observable working, when your class is extended by another one...

Answer (score 6):

Extending the built-in Observable class is a rather bad choice to implement the observer pattern as it disrupts your class hierarchy, but you know that already.

A better way would be to define your own `Observable` interface and let your class implement it. You will also need a `Listener` interface for the listener classes

The methods you would need in your `Observable` interface are `addListener(Listener listener)` and `removeListener(Listener listener)`